# SQL: How can I update a value on a column only if that value is null?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-update, where-clause

I have an SQL question which may be basic to some but is confusing me.

Here is an example of column names for a table 'Person':
PersonalID, FirstName, LastName, Car, HairColour, FavDrink, FavFood

Let's say that I input the row:

> 121312, Rayna, Pieterson, BMW123d, Brown, NULL, NULL

Now I want to update the values for this person, but only if the new value is not null, Update:

> 121312, Rayna, Pieterson, NULL, Blonde, Fanta, NULL

The new row needs to be:

> 121312, Rayna, Pieterson, BMW123d, Blonde, Fanta, NULL

So I was thinking something along the lines of:

> Update Person(PersonalID, FirstName, LastName, Car, HairColour,
>   FavDrink, FavFood) set Car = @Car (where @Car is not null), HairColour
>   = @HairColour (where @HairColour...)... etc.

My only concern is that I can't group all the conditions at the end of the query because it will require all the values to have the same condition. Can't i do something like Update HairColour if @HairColour is not Null

Comment: Wow: 5 minutes of silence, then 4 people answering the same thing at the same time. :-)

Comment: Haha i know it's great isn't it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Id use coalesce for this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

```
update Person
set Car = coalesce(@Car, Car), HairColour = coalesce(@HairColour, HairColour)
```

Comment: MySQL reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I was thinking of using this function but couldn't understand how it worked exactly. Cheers works a dream

Answer (score 15):

The following should work:

```
UPDATE Person
   SET Car = ISNULL(@Car, Car),
       HairColour = ISNULL(@HairColour, HairColour),
       ...
```

It uses the SQL Server [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function, which returns

- the first value if it is non-null,
- or, otherwise, the second value (which, in this case, is the current value of the row).

Comment: This also works just as well as using coalesce. Thanks for your help. Sorry i accepted the other answer as they were first to reply.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `isnull` function:

```
update Person
set
  Car = isnull(@Car, Car),
  HairColour = isnull(@HairColour, HairColour),
  FavDrink = isnull(@FavDrink, FavDrink),
  FavFood = isnull(@FavFood, FavFood)
where PersonalID = @PersonalID
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the column equal to itself with an isnull round it setting it to your parameter.

```
UPDATE
    YourTable
SET
   YourColumn = ISNULL(YourColumn, @yourParameter)
WHERE
    ID = @id
```

Comment: That's not what the question was. Quote: "update the values for this person, but only if the *new* value is not null"