# Creating more dynamic queries with objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have an API with a Post endpoint where the body is quite flexible. Basically I allow anything to be posted there and then I will serialize this body to an object, like this:

```
  public class PostBody
    {
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        public string SomeOtherValue{ get; set; }
        public string AnotherValue{ get; set; }
    }


    string body = 
   "{
            "id": "335",
            "someOtherValue": "fsdfds"
    }"

PostBody body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostBody>(body);
```

As you can see here Postbody can be populated with "AnotherValue" but it also might not depending on what the client wants to insert/update.

And lets say that my database table contains all three, "Id", "SomeOtherValue" and "AnotherValue" as columns.

**Now, how can I use dapper to dynamically insert/update this table, depending if the properties in the PostBody object are null or not? I mean **if "AnotherValue" is null**, the query should only be like this:**

```
INSERT INTO table
(
[Id], [SomeOtherValue]
)
VALUES
( 
@Id, @SomeOtherValue
)
```

But **if "AnotherValue" is not null**, the query should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO table
    (
    [Id], [SomeOtherValue], [AnotherValue]
    )
    VALUES
    ( 
    @Id, @SomeOtherValue, @AnotherValue
    )
```

Is there a nice way to do this automatically like with a mapper or similar? Or else I would have to code a very long if statement, concatenating a query together. It would me messy and difficult to maintain.

Edit:

This is how my insert looks today:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Api.Actions.Commands
{
    class InsertStuffRequest
    {
        public InsertStuffRequest( string id, string SomeOtherValue, string AnotherValue)
        {
            Id=id;
            SomeOtherValue = someOtherValue;
            AnotherValue = ;notherValue;
        }


        public string Id { get; }
        
        public string SomeOtherValue { get; }
        
        public string AnotherValue { get; }

        public interface IInsertStuffCommand : IQuery<InsertStuffRequest, bool>
        {
        }

        public class InsertStuffCommand : IInsertStuffCommand
        {
            private const string Command =
                @"INSERT INTO table
    (
    [Id], [SomeOtherValue], [AnotherValue]
    )
    VALUES
    ( 
    @Id, @SomeOtherValue, @AnotherValue
    )";

            public async Task<Result<bool>> ExecuteAsync(InsertStuffRequest request,
                IApplicationContext context)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(context.StuffConnectionString))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();

                    var rowsAffected = await connection
                        .ExecuteAsyncWithRetry
                        (
                            Command, request
                        );

                    return Result.From(rowsAffected > 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will of course work fine for inserts but its more difficult for updates. Also my Post endpoint will work with different tables that have different columns.

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: @dfsdf I suspect you need [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/main/Dapper.Contrib). It provides simple, convention-based CRUD operations so you don't have to write the statements by hand

Comment: BTW `InsertStuffRequest` breaks the design of Dapper. Instead of a simple DTO, this is a Data Access Object with CRUD operations, exposing a single object's fields. Dapper is used as little more than an alternative ADO.NET syntax. It's *Dapper's* job to perform all the CRUD operations though. In fact, I suspect Dapper contains some similar code to create and execute DbCommand instances

Comment: Dapper also supports [custom type and property mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615036/134204).

Answer (score 1):

If your classes match your tables you could use [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/main/Dapper.Contrib). The library will create the appropriate INSERT or UPDATE queries based on the objects passed to it.

From the examples, for this class :

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Works by convention
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can insert new rows with :

```
connection.Insert(new Car { Name = "Volvo" });
```

or insert a list with

```
connection.Insert(cars);
```

You can update the same way:

```
connection.Update(new Car() { Id = 1, Name = "Saab" });
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly the names in the database are garbage so I have to use proper names in the API and then map them to the bad names in the db.

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question. You can use Dapper's mapping attributes or [custom type mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615036/134204). You'll have to explain what you want in the question itself so people can post code the appropriate mapping code

Comment: I have to hand it to you. It's a great solution. Thanks for introducing Dapper.Contrib. @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is just a mistake
Use your second insert:

```
INSERT INTO table
    (
    [Id], [SomeOtherValue], [AnotherValue]
    )
    VALUES
    ( 
    @Id, @SomeOtherValue, @AnotherValue
    )
```

and pass a null value (or empty string) to @AnotherValue when you haven't got value.

For the update query, you must generate a dynamic string by sqlbuilder:
(this code not tested and wrote as sample only)

```
SqlBuilder builder = new SqlBuilder();
    var update = builder.AddTemplate("UPDATE table /**set**/ OUTPUT inserted.id /**where**/");    
    builder.Set("SomeOtherValue= SomeOtherValue", new { StrSomeOtherValue});
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StrAnotherValue))
    {
        builder.Set("AnotherValue= @AnotherValue", new { StrAnotherValue });
    }
    
    builder.Where("id = @id", new { id = entityId});
    
    var result = new Result<long?>(sqlConn.ExecuteScalar<long?>(update.RawSql, update.Parameters));
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work for inserts. But my API also supports Updates. And sometimes maybe you only provide a body for one field, then all the other fields would be set to null, thus overriding previous inserted data.

Comment: I think I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675968/sql-how-can-i-update-a-value-on-a-column-only-if-that-value-is-null

ISNULL will return the first value if it is non null, otherwise it will use the column value

Comment: @dfsdf What a nice solution you have found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675968/sql-how-can-i-update-a-value-on-a-column-only-if-that-value-is-null. I think so COALESCE() can be useful but in many  complex cases SqlBuilder can help more

Comment: I have not tried isnull yet. Thanks for showing SqlBuilder, I might have use for it!

Comment: Hmm, antoher thing I was thinking of. What if the client actually wants to set the value to null, I wonder how to deal with it then,

Comment: @dsdf I think so it is related to your business. If your field is the mandatory use something like this: builder.Set("SomeOtherValue= SomeOtherValue", new { StrSomeOtherValue});  otherwise use if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StrAnotherValue)). Finally, I think the best thing to do is flowing PanagiotisKanavos 's solution. It is clear and supports all of these problems.